# How to replace a string, where two words are separated by a new line? File created in Windows

Tags: python, newline

I tried:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.FileInput('Case 1-20 for Macro.txt', mode='U',inplace=1):
    line = line.replace("price_2\nFROM","zzzzz")
    print line,
```

"Case 1-20 for Macro.txt" looks like this:

```
SELECT type_id, name_id, scenario_id, period_id, date, price_1, price_2
FROM PricesView
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't iterate over the lines, read all the contents as a string:

```
In [12]: with open(r'a.x') as f:
    ...:     content=f.read()
    ...:     print content
    ...:     content=content.replace("price_2\nFROM","zzzzz")
    ...:     print content
    ...:     
    ...: #if you want to write back that content:
    ...: with open('a.x', 'w') as f:
    ...:     f.write(content)
    ...:     

SELECT type_id, name_id, scenario_id, period_id, date, price_1, price_2
FROM PricesView
SELECT type_id, name_id, scenario_id, period_id, date, price_1, zzzzz PricesView
```

Comment: @BP_ what didn't work? you mean the output above is not what you want?

Comment: I'm saying that when I tried your solution in my file, it didn't replace the string.

Comment: @BP_ `replace` will not take effect in-place, use `content=content.replace...`, and you may also want to write back the string

Comment: Can you please edit your answer so it's a fully working example. I will tick your answer then.

Comment: still doesn't work. i have also added f.write() and f.close() after second print content. do you have do anything else? the script should 1) open the file, 2) replace strings 3) save and close the file

Comment: @BP_ didn't know you wanna write back the content. code updated